# I think I messed up the Fusion Drive on my 2TB iMac

Tags: hard-drive, macos, ssd, fusion-drive

I want to ask you how can I get back together my Fusion Drive (merge HDD and SSD together). I was installing Windows 10 and during installation it crashed and I was not able to boot in Windows neither OS X. I also lost recovery partition, so I am going to install it with internet recovery or with my installed OS X on my external HDD. Thanks for any advice

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Preparation:**

- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive)
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan).

**Rebuild Fusion Drive**

All data on the disks will be deleted.

- Booted to Internet Recovery Mode open Utilities → Terminal in the menubar and enter:
  `diskutil cs list` to get a CoreStorage listing.
- Copy the Logical Volume UUIDs one by one, if any are listed.
- Now delete all Logical Volumes with `diskutil cs deleteVolume LVUUID`.
- Copy the Logical Volume Group UUID, if any is listed. It's the first listed in the listing of `diskutil cs list`.
- Then delete the Logical Volume Group with `diskutil cs delete LVGUUID`.
- Enter `exit` and quit *Terminal*
- Open *Disk Utility*. Enter 'Ignore' if you are asked to fix the drives.
- Choose your SSD and erase it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled), GUID Partiton table and hit Erase.
  Please check that the size is ~121 GB

  Example:

  [image: ssd]
- Choose your HDD and erase it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled), GUID Partiton table and hit Erase.
  Please check that the size is ~2 TB

  Example:

  [image: hdd]
- Quit Disk Utility and open Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list`

  Example (your disk identifiers and sizes are different of course: Your volume SSD probably has the Identifier disk0s2 and the size 121 GB and your volume HDD probably has the Identifier disk1s2 and the size 2.0 TB):

  [image: diskutil]
- Enter `diskutil cs create "Name" IdentifierSSD IdentifierHDD`
  In your case probably `diskutil cs create "Macintosh HD" disk0s2 disk1s2`.

  Copy the resulting LVGUUID

  Example:

  [image: cscreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs CreateVolume LVGUUID jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%`.

  Example:

  [image: lvcreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs list`
  Check the size of your Logical Volume. It should have the size ~1.121 TB
- Quit *Terminal*
- Open *Disk Utility* and check your newly created volume for errors
- Quit *Disk Utility*
- Open *Restore OS X*. Install and configure OS X. The original OS X your Mac came with will be installed.
- After configuring OS X, download the newest available system installer with *App Store* and upgrade your system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootcamp or a Windows VM (aka Parallels) ? You can use the SSD as the boot drive for the applications and create a partition on the primary HD.

Comment: I used to have on VM but then I tried Bootcamp and this have happened. So now I just want the factory settings, so I want to merge drives back together as they were before with original Fusion drive.